# Nginx: 28 directory index of "/var/www/html/ " is forbidden,

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx

I'm working with ubuntu 16.04 and nginx 1.10 , and I've been following https://www.linuxbabe.com/security/letsencrypt-webroot-tls-certificate to get a certificate installed. I have successfully got the certs and following the directions I updated my nginx config file to:

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
     return 301 https:$server_name$request_uri;

     location /static {
         alias /home/deploy/sites/mysite.com/static;
     }
     location / {
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/mysocket.socket;
     }

     location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
             default_type "text/plain";
                 root /var/www/html;
     }
 }

 server {
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
     root /var/www/html;

     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;

     ssl_session_timeout 1d;
     ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
     ssl_session_tickets off;
     ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

     ssl_ciphers
                                                                                 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-   GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-      AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-       SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-    CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;


}
```

when I run sudo nginx -T , I'm not getting errors.

But when I open my site I get a 403 error.

The error log at /var/log/nginx shows:

```
 2017/05/20 07:59:47 [notice] 21911#21911: signal process started
 2017/05/20 07:59:58 [error] 21913#21913: *28 directory index of "/var/www/html/ " is forbidden, client: 216.xx.xx.xx, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /  HTTP/2.0", host: "mysite.com"
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of `location` blocks in the wrong `server` block. I am thinking that everything after the `return` should be in the other block.

If you want `/.well-known` to be accessible over `http`, you will need to remove the HSTS header from the `https` server.

Currently, you have a `root` statement in the `https` server, and nothing else (other than the SSL stuff). So the default action is to serve `/var/www/html/index.html` (if it exists) or return 403.